# Radio button with iCheck only change value when confirm return true

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

I create the modern radio buttons with [iCheck](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/) and there are four options. When user change radio button, I popup a confirm message "Are you sure?"

If confirm return false, I want to back the previous radio button, but now It don't back to the previous radio.

This is a part of code:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div style="padding-left:20px; line-height:2;">
      <input type="radio" id="main-category1" name="main-category" value="1" > 1. <br>
      <input type="radio" id="main-category2" name="main-category" value="2" > 2. <br>
      <input type="radio" id="main-category3" name="main-category" value="3" > 3. <br>
      <input type="radio" id="main-category4" name="main-category" value="4" > 4. <br>
      <input type="radio" id="main-category5" name="main-category" value="5" > 5. <br>
    </div>
  </form>

<scirpt>
$('input').on('ifClicked', function(event){        
   msg = confirm('Are you sure?');
   var cual= this;
   if(msg == false) {
       $('#main-category3').iCheck('check'); // It's check to new value and check to 3rd radio, but I want to check only 3rd radio. 
   }   
});
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you add `return false`?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly; add return false --> It's not happend

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('input').on('click', function(event) {
      msg = confirm('Are you sure?');
      var cual = this;
      if (msg == false) {
        $('#main-category3').attr("checked",true);
        // It's check to new value and check to 3rd radio, but I want to check only 3rd radio. 
      }
    });
  </script>
```

I created a plunk for your code and made a correction

http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:1986619?p=preview

Comment: `ifClicked` is a valid event within the iCheck plugin.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Thank you for that information. Appreciate it. The Plunk did not refer it. I am adding it now.